# Monitoring In Ear Binaural Recording 

Tags: binaural, monitoring

Hi,

I've checked almost all the binaural questions, but please excuse me if it has already been answered. I normally record fake-binaural with my DPA4060's sticking out of my headphones (DT770). I'm wondering how one monitors the levels/audio when recording in-ear binaural.
Do you check levels beforehand and assume everything will be fine as long as it's not too loud? Or are there binaural mic's out there with small earphones in them, that allow soft monitoring levels?

Thanks in advance!

Arnoud

Comment: I usually just set the levels right, at a safe level and then listen with only my ears while recording, while checking the meters when it's getting loud. If you are sure your complete system works properly then  you shouldn't have any problems right?


Comment: True, but you'll never notice when something does go wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a pair of in-ear binaural mics for a few months now (Soundman OKM II) and not being able to monitor has been one of the main drawbacks. However, I think the positives definitely outweigh the negatives. I generally record *blind* and have often had moments where I thought I'd recorded something amazing only to find out later that the recording had been ruined by wind noise (another drawback to in-ear binaurals) or some other unwanted factor. It took me quite some time before I got to know at what level I should be recording at and when I should apply a -20dB cut, but once over that little learning curve I have rarely had problems with the recordings I've made.

Comment: I'm mostly concerned about wirestrain noise and wind indeed. I can't look at my meters constantly since that will ruin the sound image. But thanks for the response, I'll just have to ride the curve.

Comment: Hi Colin, another question, what type of windprotection do you use? Arnoud

Comment: My mics have foam windshields, but these aren't sufficient enough in strong wind. One of the drawbacks. There are other windshield options but they make your stealthiness much less. 

Comment: Thanks! Stealthiness is not my concern at the moment. What do you consider 'strong wind' when using the okm II? 

Comment: Well, we're not really talking about gale force here. The OKM IIs are pretty sensitive so any kind of gust will usually effect the recording. But I'm not really sure how to describe just how strong their resistance will go in windy conditions. I have a system where as soon as I can feel the wind blowing in my face, I'll try my best to (slowly) adjust my positioning until I don't feel the wind anymore. 

Answer (score 0):

I think these are exactly what you are looking for:
[Roland Cs-10EM](http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/roland-cs10em-binaural-inear-headphones-p-564.html)
Might get a pair myself!!